# Running Python script via ssh causes CPU to underperform

Tags: python, ssh, cpu, ram

I am running a Python script via ssh. The machine has 16 GB RAM.

When I run the script, I see this:

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND           
26420 username  20   0 20.1g  15g 2536 D  1.0 96.8   0:29.54 python
```

Now, it does run, though it takes days to output the intended outputs. My question is: the program is using over 90% RAM; why does it use less than 1% CPU? Is there a correlation here?

Comment: It would be nice if you give more details as for what the script does and maybe also post the script code in the question body.

Comment: How is ssh relevant here? Are you implying the script runs differently when it's not run through ssh?